# iOS (4.3) safari issue with Audio (multiple files)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, ios4

I'm having an issue with the AUDIO tag. I have an HTML page (with javascript) where 4 sound files play in succession. In iOS 5, and latest safari, things play wonderfully, but in 4.3(.2) things aren't working.

Below are the MANY solutions I have tried. It should be noted that playing ONE sound file on a page is not a problem. I have Voice Over audio playing on page-load for most of my pages and that works fine.

All of the below methods work perfectly in 5.0 and latest desktop safari, just not in iOS 4.3 simulator/device:

1) Have a hidden div, set innerHTML = an tag with the appropriate src file
1a) onended - clear div innerHTML, load next audio file
1b) setTimeout, delay 2 seconds between each file (which is 1 second long) then load next sound
2) Hidden div, set innerHTML = 4 audio tags
2a) onended - .play() next audio file
2b) setTimeout - .play() next audio file
3) replaced with EMBED
4) replaced with OBJECT
5) Used javascript only: 
    a = new Audio(src); a.play();

The behavior is best described as "wonky". Sometimes only 1 sound will play, others two will play, rarely 3. Sometimes the first will repeat 4 times (while the debug displays that 4 different sounds should have played)

My ultimate goal is to have a random sequence of 4 sounds played in succession.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like if I do everything with 1 javascript audio control, things work better...

I created a global audio control:

```
var a=new Audio();
```

Whenever I wanted to play a sound I did:

```
a.pause(); 
a.src='newfile.m4a'; 
a.play();
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner way of implementing audio without having to embed the sound on the page. Makes a big difference if there are a number of sounds that can be played. May have usability problems with large audio files or if the user has a very slow internet connection,